# MongoDB > Text Query > Similar words

Tags: mongodb

How can i search for similar word in mongo text query

Example of similar words : 'Jean' 'Jeann' 'Jeean' 'Jeaan'

I tried mongo's text query, best thing i found is that if 2 documents with same word but different value, i can get them with the text score

Example of what i tried:

Im searching for 'Jean'

```
{
 'name': 'Jean foo',
 'somethingElse': ['one', 'two', 'three']
},
{
 'name': 'Jean bar',
 'somethingElse': ['one']
},
,
{
 'name': 'Jean',
 'somethingElse': ['one']
}
```

I get the 3 documents with the text score, it works perfectly but i cannot get a document like this

```
{
 'name': 'Jeaan',
 'somethingElse': ['one']
}
```

Data Example :

```
{
 'name': 'Jean',
 'somethingElse': ['one', 'two', 'three']
},
{
 'name': 'Jeaan',
 'somethingElse': ['one']
}
{
 'somethingElse': 'Jeann',
 'categories': ['one', 'two']
}
```

Comment: You should give a better definition of "similar words". Your example can be solved with a regex:  `db.collection.find({ name: { $regex: "J+e+a+n+"}})`

Comment: In this example , if i query 'Jean' i get the first 2 docs with textScore of 0.75 and the 3rd with 1 which is perfect
```
{
 'name': 'Jean foo',
 'somethingElse': ['one', 'two', 'three']
},
{
 'name': 'Jean bar',
 'somethingElse': ['one']
},
,
{
 'name': 'Jean',
 'somethingElse': ['one']
}
```

But if i have a document like this i expect it to be returned with a score for example of 0.3 but it is not being returned at all because it doesn't match the exact name  'Jean'

```
{
 'name': 'Jeaaan',
 'somethingElse': ['one']
}

```

Answer (score 0):

Create text index on name column:

Created collection with the name shop:

```
 db.shop.insertMany([{
    ...  'name': 'Jean',
    ...  'somethingElse': ['one', 'two', 'three']
    ... },
    ... {
    ...  'name': 'Jeaan',
    ...  'somethingElse': ['one']
    ... },
    ... {
    ...  'somethingElse': 'Jeann',
    ...  'categories': ['one', 'two']
    ... }])
    {
            "acknowledged" : true,
            "insertedIds" : [
                    ObjectId("5d42c7be2f40da142ffb5106"),
                    ObjectId("5d42c7be2f40da142ffb5107"),
                    ObjectId("5d42c7be2f40da142ffb5108")
            ]
    }
```

Step2: Created Text index on name field:

```
db.shop.createIndex({name:"text"})
```

Step3:

```
db.shop.find({$text:{$search:"Jean Jeann Jeean Jeaan"}})
```

Output:

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d42c7be2f40da142ffb5107"), "name" : "Jeaan", "somethingElse" : [ "one" ] }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d42c7be2f40da142ffb5106"), "name" : "Jean", "somethingElse" : [ "one", "two", "three" ] }
```

Comment: That's not what im looking for, simply if im searching for name 'James' i want the documents with 'Jamesss' 'Jamees' to be returned with a relevance score.. im afraid that is not possible in mongo